# Why is advanced indexing creating a copy of a sliced matrix?

Tags: python, matrix-indexing

If we are assigning only a part of a matrix A to another variable (view1), this variable will only display a view of the appertaining components of the matrix. However, if the Advanced indexing is used to assign a part of a matrix A to another variable (view2), a copy of the appertaining components of the matrix will be created. Why does the Advanced indexing (when we have a list for the slicing parameter instead of a tuple sequence object) does that? I have gone through the documentation, but I still do not understand it.

[Advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)

```
A = np.arange(15)
A = A.reshape((3,5))
print(A, "\n")
view1 = A[:, [3]]
print("'view1' before the matrix A change =", view1)
view2 = A[:, 3]
print("'view2' before the matrix A change =", view2, "\n")
# Change in the 4th column od the matrix A
A[:, 3] = 5
print(A, "\n")
print("'view1' after the matrix A change =", view1)
print("'view2' after the matrix A change =", view2)
```

Comment: semi off topic, to format the code, copy and paste your code in your question, highlight it and hit `ctrl` + `k`. Make sure you have a new (blank) line before the first line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll explain exactly what your code does. It creates a two-dimensional 3x5 matrix `A` then from that creates a two-dimensional 3x1 column matrix `view1` and a one-dimensional vector `view2`. The information in `view1` and `view2` is the same--the fourth column of matrix `A`. Your code then changes matrix `A`, and `view2` also receives those changes but `view1` is not changed. The conclusion is that `view2` is actually a *view* of `A`--it is not separate data but merely looks at a part of matrix `A`. However, `view1` is a *copy* of the information in `A` when `view1` was created--it is separate data that just agrees with `A` at the start but can diverge.

The vector `view2` is a view of `A` since its definition `A[:, 3]` is a basic slice of `A`--the fourth column. The column matrix `view1` is a copy since its definition `A[:, [3]]` is "advanced indexing" or "fancy indexing". The brackets around the `3` prevent it from being a basic slice. A slight change in the definition shows why: `view3 = A[:, [3,0,1]]` creates a 3x3 matrix that contains the fourth, first, and second columns of `A`, in that order.

Your question is a good one: the results of a slice and of advanced indexing look similar, so why is the first a view and the second a copy?

**The short answer is: for convenience and speed**, like many other decisions in computer science.

Here is a graphic that shows how a numpy array is set in memory, in contrast to Python's standard list. (This graphic is from *Python Data Science Handbook*, chapter 2, section 1.)

[image]

We see that numpy's arrays are not very flexible. There is a place for the dimensions of the array--3x5 for `A`, 3x1 for `view1`, 3 for `view2`, and 3x3 for `view3`. After than come the *strides*, which basically are the offsets to go from one cell to the next along a particular dimension. And that's about it for the array, other than the item values themselves. That keeps the memory usage low but prevents some fancy things that Python's lists-within-lists can do. (I simplify some details here.)

In your example, the data for `A` is

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

The first dimension is the row, and to go from a cell to the corresponding cell in the next row, numpy must jump 5 values. E.g. the value in the top row and fourth column is `3`. Moving to the next row, we move 5 more places to see the value `8`, and to get the next row was move 5 more places to get the value `13`. The second dimension is the column, and the stride for that is 1: the value after the `3` changing only the column is `4`. So the strides for matrix `A` are `5` and `1`.

The slice for `view2` is simple, so the data *is the same data as that for matrix `A`*. There is no need to copy the data. So how does `view2` see the same differently from `A`? Instead of pointing to the value `0`, as `A`'s data pointer does, `view2`'s data pointer points to the `3` in the same data. Its dimensions block says there is only one dimension with 3 values. It has only one stride, but its stride is `5`. In other words, the first value in `view2` is `3`, and to find the next value numpy skips `5` (the stride) locations to find the `8`, then again to find the `13`. The array `view2` uses the same data as `A` but different dimensions and strides, so it looks different. In other words, it is a *view* of `A`.

The advanced indexing for `view3` is different. In the same row, the values jump from the fourth column to the first column to the second column of `A`. There is no stride that could possibly tell numpy to access the values in that way. Therefore, numpy must copy some of the data from `A` to make a new, simple array to handle `view3`. A copy is made because a view is impossible. To clarify, this is `view3`:

```
[[ 3  0  1]
 [ 8  5  6]
 [13 10 11]]
```

Now for your question: what about `view1`? It would have been *possible* for numpy to make that a view, for that particular case. However, `view1` was created through advanced indexing, and we have seen that it is frequently impossible to do views for those. Therefore, numpy takes the convenient, fast, and consistent route and declares that all occasions of advance indexing create copies, even in cases where views are possible. This is convenient, because numpy does not need to try to figure out if a view is possible. It is fast, and remember that one of the main advantages of numpy is that it is fast, so leaving out the attempt to create a view when possible speeds things up. And it is consistent, since all uses of advanced indexing create copies, rather than some creating views and some creating copies.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and comprehensive reply. I am still trying to understand it completely combining it sometimes with the documentation. I have a question regarding the _view3_ variable. Did you maybe have _view1_ actually in mind?

Comment: @Mike: My mistakes were more in confusing `view1` and `view2`. I think I have corrected my mistakes--let me know if you see any more.

Comment: @Mike: If my answer was helpful, and if no better answer comes along soon, please "accept" my answer. You do that by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered. When you get more "reputation" points here, you will be able to up-vote all the useful answers (you can accept only one answer).

Comment: I will accept your answer as soon as I will understand it. I need to go thoroughly over it again.